# How to use list.contains without implementation of equals and hashcode?

Tags: java

This is my Role class

```
public class Role{
 int id
 String role

 //getters and setters
}
```

I have a list of role and I want to know if a given string matches role.role
If I use `list.contains("someString")` without implementation of `equals` and `hashcode`, this will not work.

Comment: That is correct. You need to implement at least `equals` to make `contains` work (and then should really implement `hashCode` to match it).

Comment: Option 1 in the top-voted answer for the duplicate would work well here.

Comment: Is there other way? I don't want to implement equals and hashcode.

Comment: Option 1 in the top-voted answer for the duplicate would work well here, no need to use `contains` (and thus implement `equals`).